# React Native FirebaseError: Function Query.startAfter() requires a valid first argument, but it was undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

So Im receiving an error or:

> FirebaseError: Function Query.startAfter() requires a valid
> first argument, but it was undefined.

My code:

```
getMore = async () => {
    let check = {};
    check = this.state.lastDoc;

    console.log(check); //returns a big object I will post below.
    if (check) {
      this.setState({ isMoreLoading: true });

      setTimeout(async () => {
        let snapshot = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("posts")
          .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
          .startAfter(check.data().id)
          .limit(2)
          .get();
  };
```

So I guess this error is about `firebase`.

> WHAT console LOG (check) RETURNS JUST BEFORE BEING USED FOR
> startAfter: ITS CUT A BIT BECAUSE IT COULDNT BE POSTED: ITS CUT A BIT
> BECAUSE IT COULDNT BE POSTED:

```
 QueryDocumentSnapshot {
      "_document": Document {
        "converter": [Function anonymous],
        "
            },
            "name": Object {
              "stringValue": "NoviMatko",
            },
            "text": Object {
              "stringValue": "For wh perceive laughing six did far.",
            },
            "timestamp": Object {
              "integerValue": "1604771339487",
            },
            "uid": Object {
              "stringValue": "S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13",
            },
          },
          "name": "projects/eleph-6fee9/databases/(default)/documents/posts/djoSXIPRn1RMxMq2TD4C",
          "updateTime": "2020-11-07T17:49:00.119930Z",
        },
        "version": SnapshotVersion {
          "timestamp": Timestamp {
            "nanoseconds": 119930000,
            "seconds": 1604771340,
          },
        },
      },
    
          "
              
                  "[DEFAULT]" => Object {
                    "apiKey": "AIzaSyDwUBce3WYEl78xA6aag5nzb1xh2xC8dZQ",
                    
                      "lastLoginAt": "1604691856267",
                      "phoneNumber": null,
                      "photoURL": null,
                      "providerData": Array [
                        Object {
                          "displayName": null,
                          "email": "dwdwadw@gmail.com",
                          "phoneNumber": null,
                          "photoURL": null,
                          "providerId": "password",
                          "uid": "dwdwadw@gmail.com",
                        },
                      ],
                      "redirectEventId": null,
                    
                      },
                      "tenantId": null,
                      "uid": "S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13",
                    },
                  },
                },
                "instancesDeferred": Map {},
                "name": "auth",
              },
              
                },
                "container": [Ci...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
    Got all results
    vVbq2mwrDMseBxCPDj15 => {"avatar":null,"name":"NoviMatko","text":"evoooo","timestamp":1605303464278,"uid":"S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13"}
    vG9p4xL8UqlZBkls1Xv1 => {"avatar":null,"name":"NoviMatko","text":"gdgdgdg","timestamp":1605303411975,"uid":"S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13"}
    xyyZQs5q9OLP2BdqDwJO => {"avatar":null,"name":"NoviMatko","text":"jkj","timestamp":1605136211563,"uid":"S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13"}
    jttcmEM8WFHOXxRIO9q9 => {"avatar":null,"name":"NoviMatko","text":"adawdadjnajodhjadjonadjjajdhajdnjadnjandjnadnadajdnjas","timestamp":1605116149227,"uid":"S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13"}
    qFJwWiS0dpaKFbVOWrG1 => {"avatar":null,"name":"NoviMatko","text":"gsgsefgsfsf","timestamp":1605115920543,"uid":"S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13"}
    qD8rrsexA4HrWHvCtfxR => {"avatar":null,"name":"NoviMatko","text":"JLKDBWJENKEFJOFBNKOJSBENFJKSNFJKLSNFJKSJNFJSKFNJSNFNSFNSNFNSJKLEFNSENFSNFJNSEJFNSJFNSJFNSEFNLSNF;SNFS;FH;SFJSFNSJFNSJNFJSNFJSNFNSNFNSFNSJFNSFNSF","timestamp":1605115869284,"uid":"S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13"}
    djoSXIPRn1RMxMq2TD4C => {"avatar":null,"name":"NoviMatko","text":"For who thoroughly her boy estimating conviction. Reme admire in giving. See resolved goodness felicity shy civility domestic had 
    but. Drawings offended yet answered jennings perceive laughing six did far.","timestamp":1604771339487,"uid":"S2BxNARp4Cfinttb1TK5mzAHPb13"}
    eILcb0rPOZ0Rpeoym6uX => {"avatar":"https://firebadia&token=272cfbff-3fd7-4216-a6c3-09ed612eca3e","text":"Fjjfjffj","timestamp":1604395119914,"uid":"oTPw7q2jRWcE3F92U4aXeHHTHDg1"}
    y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT => {"commentCount":3,"likeCount":5,"mood":"Yy","text":"Today is such 
    a joyful day because its Monday and at Mondays we dont do much at my work #blessed","timestamp":1592776918943,"userHandle":" NRQ2Ewhx76cWVqntRPLV1ygYHB73"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `check.data().id` was undefined, not `check`.  If you want to see the value of `check.data().id`, you should log exactly that.

What's likely happening here is that the document you have in hand here doesn't have a property called "id".  That would explain why you're seeing this error message.

If you want to use `startAfter()` correctly, you should actually just pass the entire DocumentSnapshot object to it:

```
        let snapshot = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("posts")
          .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
          .startAfter(check)
          .limit(2)
          .get();
```

For more information, see the [documentation on the pagination APIs](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#startend).

Comment: This helped me. thank u.What exactly I needed to do was understanding I dont have id field, I had to equal Auto Id with field id, and then use it here. thank u so much